# Pie not working on server. Works on local? Using Zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, zend-framework, pie-chart

I've added [pie](http://css3pie.com/) to the stylesheet, tried a variety of paths and extensions, and have added the correct MIME type (text/x-component).

Works on local but not on server...

Cheers

I'm using the standard code `behavior: url('/js/pie/PIE.htc');` also used different variations. Also added MIME type to .htaccess

Comment: share the code please.

Comment: Just using the standard code `behavior: url('/js/pie/PIE.htc');` also used different variations. Also added MIME type to .htaccess

Comment: Add the code in your question. so everyone see there and will help you better.

Comment: on server you need to give the full path, the relevant path is not working many time. hope after giving the full path, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not working ether. I'm at a loss.

Comment: What path your are using? can you show?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a directory structure as follows (in your Zend public folder):

```
\public
    \css
        style.css
    \pie
        PIE.htc
        PIE.php
        PIE.js
```

The path in `style.css` to link `PIE.htc` or `PIE.php` should be like this :

```
.selector {
    ...
    behavior('../pie/PIE.php');
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this does not work on server.